# Carousel with ng-repeat limit to 3 in one carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, uislider

I am trying to use ng-repeat with carousel. But, 3 array items to be shown in one carousel, If more length is more than three, those items to be shown in next carousel.

Small snippet below,

```
    $scope.addCampus = newCampus;   
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.campuses = [];

    function init(){
        console.log("Initing");
        $log.log("loading");
        newCampus();
    }


    function newCampus() {
        $log.log("Adding a new campus");
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        $scope.model.campuses.push({});
        }
    }

    init();
});
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-if="model.campuses.length < 9" ng-click="newCampus()">Add</button>
<div uib-carousel active="activetTestimonial" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
    <div ul-slide  ng-repeat="quickbite in model.campuses track by $index" index="$index" class="widget-slide">
        <button ng-click="showDeleteDialog($index, true)">delete {{$index}}</button>

        <form name="formTestimonial[$index]" role="form" novalidate show-validation>
            <div class="editor-div-flex editor-url">
                <div class="login-lable label-editor label-editor-logo editor-div-flex">
                    Name:
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="editor-input widget-input" type="text" ng-model="quickbite.title" name="title" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-div-flex editor-url">
                <div class="login-lable label-editor label-editor-logo text-left">
                    <div>Description:</div>
                    <div class="editor-limits">
                        ( 300 char )
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea class="editor-textarea widget-input" ng-model="quickbite.description" maxlength="300" name="description" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="model.campuses.length > 3">
    <div class="carousel-arrow widget-carousel-arrow-left">
        <button class="demo-nav testimonial-arrow" ng-click="prevQuickbiteSlide()">
            <img src="/content/images/editor/left.png">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-arrow  widget-carousel-arrow-right">
        <button class="demo-nav testimonial-arrow" ng-click="nextQuiclbiteSlide()">
            <img src="/content/images/editor/right.png">
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I have to show 3 items in one carousel. If the array items are more than 3 it should show in next carousel.

Ultimately, 1st carousel will have array[0], array[1], and array[2]. The 2nd carousel will have array[3], array[4] and array[5]

Answer (score 0):

I would chunk the `campuses` array in multiple arrays with each 3 items in it using this custom chunk method:

```
var ceil = Math.ceil;

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'chunk', {value: function(n) {
   return Array(ceil(this.length/n)).fill().map((_,i) => this.slice(i*n,i*n+n));
}});
```

Simply call this method on your array, like so: `[0,1,2,3,4,5].chunk(3)`.

Comment: you would need two `ng-repeat`s. One outer repeat for every carousel, and one inner for all the items in the respective array.

Comment: can u post any sample snippet as per my snippet in code . Am new bee in angular. So please help me out with snippet if pposible